# Magento 2 - Changing reference to Cart to Basket across site

Tags: magento2, cart, language

I would like to change all reference of Cart to Basket, across the site.

I have changed reference to this in the .CSV but no change across the website after clearing the cache.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Please follow devDocs, I hope you will get this answer.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html

Please let me know, still you getting this issue.

Comment: I have tried following the steps in the second link but still no luck. Also how does it work for the templates that have html to define the titles. Seems like at a lot of it is manual?